# WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed always returns false when restarting app

Tags: push-notification, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I'm working in a mobilefirst 6.3 hybrid app with push notifications, and i'm having a problem with my suscriptions, when the app starts the WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed returns false, even if i just suscribe that user to the same event.

i have to suscribe in all session my user each time i want the user to receive the suscription inside the app, but this method in my adapter which logs the user suscription:

```
function deviceSubscribeFuncCantRes(userSubscription, deviceSubscription) {
    WL.Logger.info(">> deviceSubscribeFunc");
    WL.Logger.info(userSubscription);
    WL.Logger.info(deviceSubscription);
}
```

and only triggers the first time the user suscribe so the problem seems to be in the app suscription

From outise my app, the push still keep coming even if the WL.Client.Push.isSubscribed returns false and i dont suscribe the user in the session

the question is, I must suscribe to the event in each session? or is this a bug?

Comment: Does this issue happen also in the sample app or only in your app? If only yours then please provide your implementation.

Comment: In Eventsource notifications, push subscription status is tied to your user identity. isSubscribed() returns true only after you have authenticated ( as the user ) successfully. When you restart your application, are you connecting to the server and authenticating successfully, before trying isSubscribed()?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Vivin in the comments:

> In Eventsource notifications, push subscription status is tied to your user identity. isSubscribed() returns true only after you have authenticated ( as the user ) successfully.

When you restart your application, are you connecting to the server and authenticating successfully, before trying isSubscribed()?

Ensure for example that you are correctly protecting the application with a security test in application-descriptor.xml. If you perform a connect() attempt on application, this will prompt the login screen to display, thus having the user login first before checking if already subscribed. This of course all depends on your application logic...

Comment: i put 2 buttons in my app to test this. which appears after a login success. one for suscribe and one for test if the user is suscribed, and i saw that the WL.Client.Push.onReadyToSubscribe event trigger twice in the app to.